# Excel vba: the same code becomes slow if get properties are added to a class

Tags: performance, object-oriented, vba, excel, classes

I have a main sub that makes use of a `Client` class: creates an array with `100 000` `Clients` and loops over the array `100` times, each time setting a different random number to each `Client`.

```
  Sub start()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim clientsColl() As Client
    ReDim clientsColl(1 To 100000) As Client

'    Dim clientsColl As Collection
'    Set clientsColl = New Collection

    For j = 1 To 100000
        Set clientsColl(j) = New Client

        'clientsColl.Add New Client
        clientsColl(j).setClientName = "Client_" & j
    Next

    'Dim clientCopy As Client
    Dim clientCopy As Variant
    For i = 1 To 100
        For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
            clientCopy.generateRandom
        Next
    Next


    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

Client class:

```
Option Explicit

Private clientname As String
Private identityNumber As String
Private creditRating As String

Private contractTenor As Long
Private contractNumber As String
Private contractRate As Double

Private totalReserves As Double
Private totalReservesRate As Double

Private debtType As String
Private totalDebt As Double

Private lossRatio As Double
Private totalLoss As Variant
Private totalProfit As Double

Private totalPd As Double
Private totalLgd As Double

Private simulationCount As Long
Private randomNumber As Double
Private outcome As Integer

Private loss As Double
Private profit As Double

Private sumLosses() As Double
Private sumProfits() As Double
Private sumResults() As Double

Private averageDebtInfo As Double

Public Sub generateRandom()
    randomNumber = Rnd()
End Sub

Public Property Get getClientName()
    getClientName = clientName
End Property

Public Property Let setClientName(value As String)
    clientName = value
End Property
```

However, this code takes different time to run, depending whether the `Client` class has the `Get` and `Let` properties or not. The current version of the class posted above runs in about `25` seconds. If I add several `Get` properties to get things like `identityNumber` or `contractRate` it would take about `1 minute 25 seconds`.

Why does adding simple `Get` properties affect the code so much? Can anything be done about it? I can't afford this code to run any more than 30 seconds..

**EDIT:**

`GET` statements that slow down everything:

```
Public Property Get getAverageDebtInfo()
    getAverageDebtInfo = averageDebtInfo
End Property

Public Property Get getSumResultsArray()
    getSumResultsArray = sumResults
End Property

Public Property Get getSumResults(simulation As Long)
    getSumResults = sumResults(simulation)
End Property

Public Property Get getLossRatio()
    getLossRatio = lossRatio
End Property

Public Property Get getTotalReservesRate()
    getTotalReservesRate = totalReservesRate
End Property

Public Property Get getProfit()
    getProfit = profit
End Property

Public Property Get getSumProfitsArray()
    getSumProfitsArray = sumProfits
End Property

Public Property Get getSumProfits(simulation As Long)
    getSumProfits = sumProfits(simulation)
End Property

Public Property Get getContractTenor()
    getContractTenor = contractTenor
End Property

Public Property Get getContractNumber()
    getContractNumber = contractNumber
End Property

Public Property Get getDebtType()
    getDebtType = debtType
End Property

Public Property Get getContractRate()
    getContractRate = contractRate
End Property

Public Property Get getTotalReserves()
    getTotalReserves = totalReserves
End Property

Public Property Get getSumLossesArray()
    getSumLossesArray = sumLosses
End Property

Public Property Get getSumLosses(simulation As Long)
    getSumLosses = sumLosses(simulation)
End Property

Public Property Get getLoss()
    getLoss = loss
End Property

Public Property Get getOutcome()
    getOutcome = outcome
End Property

Private Property Get getSimulationCount()
    getSimulationCount = simulationCount
End Property

Public Property Get getRandomNumber()
    getRandomNumber = randomNumber
End Property

Public Property Get getTotalLoss()
    getTotalLoss = totalLoss
End Property

Public Property Get getTotalProfit()
    getTotalProfit = totalProfit
End Property

Public Property Get getTotalDebt()
    getTotalDebt = totalDebt
End Property

Public Property Get getTotalLgd()
    getTotalLgd = totalLgd
End Property

Public Property Get getCreditRating()
    getCreditRating = creditRating
End Property

Public Property Get getTotalPd()
        getTotalPd = totalPd
End Property

Public Property Get getIdentityNumber()
    getIdentityNumber = identityNumber
End Property
```

Comment: You should reduce the number of times that you Update the StatusBar `If j mod 10000 = 0 Then   Application.StatusBar = "Getting client " & j`.  I'm interested in seeing what the real Gurus would have to say about the extra overhead added by the Let and Get.

Comment: "If I add several Get properties..." - and where would these getters be invoked? In the statusbar loop? The problem is with updating the statusbar, not with the properties. Also objects are better off in a `Collection` iterated with a `For Each` loop, and your properties are wrong: you mean to have one member with get and let accessors, but what you have is one read-only property and then one write-only property. The two accessors need to have the same name for VBA to understand that they're two accessors for the same property.

Comment: Constantly updating the status bar like this, is not only killing your performance, it also makes the `ScreenUpdating` toggle completely useless.

Comment: @ThomasInzina the problem is that the extra properties are hypothetical, and we can't review hypothetical code. I doubt the getters are the problem. Wrong iterator type (`Variant`) is forcing late-bound member resolution, and a %-based progress indicator that doesn't repaint Excel at every single iteration would go a long way towards improving performance here.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I didn't think that simple Getters and Setters would cause a 300% increase in processing time.  Its interesting that Objects can be iterated over faster in a Collection than an Array.

Comment: @ThomasInzina getters, no. but Variant overhead times 100,000 can get you there ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug it is my understanding that because collections in the VBA are not Typed, all objects stored in a Collections are stored as a Variant. Does that mean that referencing Items in a Collection also causes late-bound member resolution? Collections also have additional overhead to support a linked-list like lookup.  I would think that a Typed Array would out perform a Collection when using a simple For Each iterator.

Comment: @Mat's Mug I tried to remove the `Application.StatusBar` statements alltogether, but it didn't influence the the performance time a lot. The difference, unfortunatelly, stayed the same. I edited the question and added the `GET` statements that slow down the code. I'll try to convert `clientsColl` to `Collection` and `clientCopy` to `Client` and write later how it went.

Comment: @Mat's Mug♦ I changed `clientsColl` to `Collection`. Then I run the code both with and without getters: when I ran it with getters it took about `53` seconds, when I ran it without getters it took near `51`seconds as well. So while transfering `clientsColl` to `Collection` *decreased* the execution time for **with-getters** case (from `1` minute `25-30` seconds to `53` seconds), it *increased* execution time for a **without-getters** case (from `25` seconds to `51` seconds).

Comment: @Mat's Mug♦ I changed the `start` sub in the question: added a `clientsColl` declaration as `Collection`, so that it's possible to switch between `clientsColl` being an `array` and a `Collection`.

Comment: You mean just *having* the getters slows down the whole thing? Are they invoked anywhere?

Comment: @Mat's Mug♦ I figured it out - there was a `Class_Initialize` that created 3 arrays of size `100` for each client. I wouldn't have expected it to slow the time down so significantly.

Comment: @Mat's Mug♦  However there still stands the fact that replacing `clientsColl` with `Collection` increases the execution time, rather than decreases.

Comment: @Thomas Inzina It looks like you were right about `Collections` vs `arrays` thing. In this example `array` is faster than `Collection`.

Comment: See, this is why we require as much context as possible. Code is much easier to review when it's pasted straight from the IDE rather than manipulated and trimmed and boiled-down.

Comment: @ThomasInzina forgot to reply about variant overhead in a collection: if the `For Each` iterator  is correctly typed, then no, you don't resolve any members off a `Variant`. All the collection needs is pointer locations; the collection isn't storing anything but *references* to objects, their type makes no difference... as long as they're objects.

Comment: @Mat'sMug that makes sense.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Using an **User Defined Type (UDT)** to store the information should give you the best performance.

It took 23.54 second to initiate 100K Clients and 20.46 second to assign the random number 100 times on my PC.

Using an UDT Array, it took 1.46 second to initiate the Array and assign the random numbers 100 times.

```
Private Type ClientInfo
    clientname As String
    identityNumber As String
    creditRating As String

    contractTenor As Long
    contractNumber As String
    contractRate As Double

    totalReserves As Double
    totalReservesRate As Double

    debtType As String
    totalDebt As Double

    lossRatio As Double
    totalLoss As Variant
    totalProfit As Double

    totalPd As Double
    totalLgd As Double

    simulationCount As Long
    randomNumber As Double
    outcome As Integer

    loss As Double
    profit As Double

    sumLosses() As Double
    sumProfits() As Double
    sumResults() As Double
End Type

Public clients() As ClientInfo

Public Sub Init_Clients()
    ReDim clients(1 To 100000)
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To 100000
        clients(j).clientname = "Client_" & j
    Next

    generateRandomNumbers
End Sub

Private Sub generateRandomNumbers()
    Dim x As Long, i As Long

    For i = 1 To 100
        For x = 1 To UBound(clients)
            clients(x).randomNumber = Rnd
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: By the time that you add all the functionality, you will have tested your code hundreds of times.  Working with a much smaller dataset, perhaps 100 Clients, will save you many hours of waiting.

Comment: `Public anything As SomePrivateType` strikes my .net-polluted brain as inconsistent accessibility. Might work, but in my experience using UDT's as if they were objects you can pass around is inevitavly going to start a fight with the VBA compiler. YMMV.